# Get a parameter pack from variable argument

Tags: c++

I'm trying to get a parameter pack from the list of arguments passed to a macro.

```
template<std::size_t N, class T, class... Ts>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
constexpr bool myFunctionHelper(const char (&fmt)[N], std::size_t n);

template <std::size_t N, typename... Ts>
constexpr bool myFunction(const char (&fmt)[N]) {
  return myFunctionHelper<N, Ts...>(fmt, 0);
}

#define FNC(fmt, ...)                                                       \                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
  do {                                                                      \                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    static_assert(myFunction<sizeof(fmt), decltype...(__VA_ARGS__)>(fmt),   \
                  "Incorrect arg types");                                   \
  } while (false)
```

But decltype doesn't work as above (sizeof does though). Is there some method to get the parameter pack?

It works if I pass the args to the myFunction and let compiler deduce the template type, but I can't pass the args further. args need not be constexpr.

Edit:

`decltype(arg)` gives us the type of arg for any object. Here I'm trying to get the type info of multiple arguments as a parameter pack. If I use `decltype(__VA_ARGS__)`, the build succeeds but it just gives me the type of the last param in the `__VA_ARGS__`. For eg:

```
decltype(1, "test", 4.0)
```

would translate to just `float`.

There doesn't exists anything like `decltype...(args)` (`sizeof...(__VA_ARGS__)` does though).

FNC would be used as follows

```
FNC("%d, %s, %0.2f\n", 1, "test", 4.0);
```

Comment: Please indicate exactly how this doesn't work. If it doesn't compile, please post the verbatim error message. Also, show an example of how you're using `FNC`.

Comment: You seem to expect `decltype...(1, 2, 3)` to expand to `int, int, int`. Instead, it's a syntax error: there ain't no such thing as `decltype...` . You'd have to pass `__VA_ARGS__` to `myFunction` as arguments, and allow their types to be deduced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along these lines, perhaps (not tested):

```
template <std::size_t N, typename Tuple, size_t... Is>
constexpr bool myFunction1(const char (&fmt)[N], std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
  return myFunction<N, std::tuple_element_t<Is, Tuple>...>(fmt);
}

template <std::size_t N, typename Tuple>
constexpr bool myFunction2(const char (&fmt)[N]) {
  return myFunction1<N, Tuple>(fmt, std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size_v<Tuple>>{});
}
```

The macro would do

```
myFunction2<sizeof(fmt), decltype(std::make_tuple(__VA_ARGS__))>(fmt)
```

Comment: This works. I was thinking about this, but was really confused around the ... syntax with std::tuple_element_t. Thanks a lot!